# Why am I seeing different Extended Properties on a table via SMO vs. the SQL Server Provider?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I set the value for an extended property with the name "MS_Description" on a table. I'm then trying to retrieve this via PowerShell.

My first method was using the PowerShell SQL Server Provider:

```
gci SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDatabase\Tables\dbo.MyTable\ExtendedProperties | Select -exp Value
```

This returns an old value.

Next, I tried retrieving it via SMO:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "localhost"
$server.Databases["MyDatabase"].Tables["MyTable"].ExtendedProperties[0].Value
```

This correctly returns the updated value.

Why the difference? At first, I suspected there was a delay before the SQL Server Provider gets updated, but half an hour later, it's still showing the same old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After way too long investigating this, I found that I just need to call the Refresh() method first:

```
$path = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDatabase\Tables\dbo.MyTable\ExtendedProperties"
(gci $path).Refresh()
gci $path | Select -exp Value
```